# Watermark detection using Deep Learning

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, cnn, computer-vision

I have images with and without watermark. There is only one type of watermark. I have tried `VGG16` transfer learning, but results were bad.

What are the methods to do image classification if it has a watermark or not?

Comment: CNNs like VGG16 are sufficient for such tasks. Maybe the problem is your data. You should add more information about your task.

Comment: @Djib2011, Data consists of cars with watermarks and without. Also there can be same Images with and without watermark in trainig set.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider finding watermark an [object detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_detection) problem, not an image classification problem. Faster R-CNN and "You only look once" (YOLO) are both general object detection architectures.

Comment: Hey, I am sorry for late response. I have tried Yolo_v2 on custom dataset, in my case it was watermarks. I labeled myself 800 images and built darknet with 1000 iterations. But I have reached max decrease of avg loss 0.6 in 800'th iteration. It did not help to detect watermarks. Settings are: batch_size 32, subdivision 16 the rest is as default

Answer (score 0):

One of the good approaches for dealing with such problems is using landmark detection. In this case, your problem will look like a combination of classification and regression task using deep neural networks. Take a look at [here](https://www.coursera.org/learn/convolutional-neural-networks/lecture/OkD3X/landmark-detection) and [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/46b2/c6727f5ccf06f53020844aa0157237ac5a89.pdf). You should specify points which have the same identity among all data-set. Then your network will try to find the position of each point. Also take a look at [here](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/software/via/).